# How can I know if a Stripe trial subscription has ended without a webhook?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am creating a Stripe customer and a subscription with a 7 day trial:

```
    const stripeCustomer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.body.email
    });

    await stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer: stripeCustomer.id,
        items: [{
            price: process.env['STRIPE_PRICE_ID']
        }],
        trial_period_days: 7
    })
```

When I check the status, it shows as `trialing`. After the trial ends, if I retrieve the subscription, it give a status of `active`. But that's not accurate because the customer didn't pay for the subscription yet.

What I want is a status that tells me that the trial has ended but that the customer has not paid yet so that I can direct the customer to the Stripe Portal when they sign in. I know there's a webhook that I can listen to, but I'd rather not worry about it at the exact moment that the trial ends. Instead, I want to deal with it when the customer signs in next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to start your subscription with a `payment_behavior` of `'default_incomplete'`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-payment_behavior

That way the subscription's status will be `incomplete` after the trial ends, only transitioning to `active` once the first invoice has been paid.

Comment: I tried that too:
```
    await stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer: stripeCustomer.id,
        items: [{
            price: process.env['STRIPE_PRICE_ID']
        }],
        payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
        trial_period_days: 7
    })
```

But when the trial ends, it transitions to `active`

Comment: Did you attach a PaymentMethod after creating the subscription but before the trial ends? The subscription should be in the `incomplete` status for approximately an hour while the invoice is created and finalized before automatically paying and transitioning to `active`. If this isn't what you're seeing you should reach out to Stripe support so they can investigate this further: https://support.stripe.com/contact